# Update field stored in jwt payload

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, jwt, passport.js

I'm using passport.js with jwt to authenticate users in my app. I'm signing the jwt token using a payload which contains among other fields, an avatar field in order to use the avatar all over my app. 
Now, I want users to be able to edit their avatar. I implemented this feature and works fine with one problem: Even though the avatar field is updated in mongodb, the changes are showing in the app only after I log out and log back in. (after the token is re-signed again)

On the front end I'm using react + redux.

How should I update this avatar field the correct way considering that is part of the payload? Should I use another approach?

Code bellow:

Login login bellow:

```
 User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        email: "Couldn't find an account."
      });
    } else {
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
        if (isMatch) {
          //User matched

          //Create JWT Payload (can contain any user info)
          const payload = {
            id: user.id,
            firstname: user.firstname,
            lastname: user.lastname,
            email: user.email,
            avatar: user.avatar
          };

          //Sign token
          //The sign method from jwt needs a payload(user info), secret and optional expiration date
          //This token is needed so the user can access private routes or any other private logic
          jwt.sign(
            payload,
            keys.secretOrKey,
            { expiresIn: "1d" },
            (err, token) => {
              res.json({
                success: true,
                token: "Bearer " + token
              });
            }
          );
        } else {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ password: "Eroare! Parola incorecta!" });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Redux action:

```
// Login

export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      //Save to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      //Set token to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth Header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    });
};

//Set logged in user

export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you can sign new JWT token after user changes avatar and send it back in the response of updateAvatar API. Then at frontend, you update localStorage with this new token

Comment: Can you share us the component code wr the Avatar is displayed and from wr the login action is called?

Comment: @HoangTrinh That's what helped me solve this problem. Post an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: @OvidiuG: Thank you for letting me know, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically in the payload of a JWT token, there are information that is useful for your frontend code such as email, username, avatar, ...

But because JWT token can only be validated and should only be issued on server (it can only be decoded at frontend because frontend doesn't know the JWT secret), so whenever you need new information in the JWT payload, you need to issue new token on server.

Apply to your situation, you need to issue new JWT token after updating avatar, and send back the JWT token in the response of updateAvatar API.

After that you can update localStorage with the new JWT token and get your new avatar at frontend.